# Cannot import React-bootstrap-treeview into .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, treeview

I am trying to import https://github.com/jonmiles/react-bootstrap-treeview as a module and I keep getting `[ts] Cannot find module 'react-bootstrap-treeview'.` I am not sure on how to import files/projects that do not have proper export statements. I am using a es5 target in my tsconfig.json

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as TreeView from 'react-bootstrap-treeview';

export class Nav extends React.Component<any, any> {
     constructor(props:any) {
        super(props);
     }

     componentWillMount() {
     }


     render() {

      // just quick and dirty var to test my nav
      var data = [
        {
          text: "Parent 1",
          nodes: [
            {
              text: "Child 1",
              nodes: [
                {
                  text: "Grandchild 1"
                },
                {
                  text: "Grandchild 2"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              text: "Child 2"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 2"
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 3"
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 4"
        },
        {
          text: "Parent 5"
        }
      ];

         return <div className="nav">
            <TreeView data={data} />
         </div>
     }
}
```